# Lubuntu 14.04 xorg-server crash every ~6 hours (NVidia)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

Every few hours my fresh Lubuntu 14.04 laptop crashes violently. Bringing Xorg server down. I have an asus ROG with geforce gtx-960m.

I looked at the X.org server log and it seems to point to a Nvidia crash.

I had problems with nouveau drivers. So I went to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) and executed

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices    
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==  
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00001043sd0000185Dbc03sc02i00  
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation  
driver   : nvidia-352 - distro non-free recommended  
driver   : nvidia-352-updates - distro non-free  
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Then proceeded to install nvidia-352 as recommended via apt-get.
It works fine except when it crashes every ~6 hours (sudden memory leak then freeze) : 
When running nvidia-settings it says driver version : 352.63
And I can run cuda and opengl just fine.

Previously I was under 14.10 then 15.04 and it was working OK until the 15.10 migration, which was so unstable I had to install back a fresh 14.04.

What did I do wrong? What I should do?

Below is the relevant part of : /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

> [ 19258.494] reporting 4 6 16 132
>   (EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
>   (EE)
>   (EE) Backtrace:
>   (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f84f1568f08]
>   (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x22b) [0x7f84f154bc3b]
>   (EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x7f84f1433042]
>   (EE) 3: /usr/bin/X (xf86PostMotionEvent+0xd6) [0x7f84f14691b6]
>   (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f84e5768000+0x521e) [0x7f84e576d21e]
>   (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f84e5768000+0x71f2) [0x7f84e576f1f2]
>   (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0x914b8) [0x7f84f14594b8]
>   (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0xb93d0) [0x7f84f14813d0]
>   (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f84ef548000+0x36d40) [0x7f84ef57ed40]
>   (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0x1a5390) [0x7f84f156d390]
>   (EE) 10: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f84ef548000+0x36d40) [0x7f84ef57ed40]
>   (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f84ef548000+0x15024b) [0x7f84ef69824b]
>   (EE) 12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0xc8ce3) [0x7f84e93f1ce3]
>   (EE) 13: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5d9472) [0x7f84e9902472]
>   (EE) 14: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5d986e) [0x7f84e990286e]
>   (EE) 15: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5d581c) [0x7f84e98fe81c]
>   (EE) 16: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5a2533) [0x7f84e98cb533]
>   (EE) 17: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5a7624) [0x7f84e98d0624]
>   (EE) 18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7f84e9329000+0x5b3e85) [0x7f84e98dce85]
>   (EE) 19: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0x5414e) [0x7f84f141c14e]
>   (EE) 20: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0x57f9b) [0x7f84f141ff9b]
>   (EE) 21: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f84ef569ec5]
>   (EE) 22: /usr/bin/X (0x7f84f13c8000+0x4352e) [0x7f84f140b52e]
>   (EE)
>   (EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
>   (EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
>   (EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  100 events have been dropped.
>   (EE)

Answer (score 0):

Answering partially my own question : I managed to get more stability by configuring nvidia-settings -> PRIME settings -> power saving mode.
It disables 3d acceleration but it's stable (more than with nouveau drivers). I just can't use cuda anymore when in this mode.

I've also tried to update the kernel (using apt-get install linux-image-3.19.0-33) but it doesn't solve the stability issue so I reverted back by apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-33.

What's more frustrating is that I got it to work fine for a few months using 14.10 and 15.04 with bumblebee (Yet I remember having a hard time configuring it (to make it use nvidia 352.037 driver version from the nvidia website and a subtle bumblebee configuration trick substituting "." for ":" in configuration file to match pci bus address), but it got totally broken by migration 15.10), but and I can't get it to work right under 14.04.

With a little luck when 16.04 will be released in a few months, those nvidia-drivers issues will be resolved.